# Mysql - select and order by two price columns as one

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

I am facing one problem with selecting data from mysql and I cant figure it out. Try to do research but without luck.

I have table with 4 columns:

```
id | name | price | discount_price
1 | Test 1 | 150  | 50
4 | test 2 | 130  | 300
2 | test 3 | 200  | 0
3 | test 4 | 130  | 10
4 | test 5 | 80  | 0
```

And I need to select data and order them by price and if discount_price is not "ZERO", than order by price_discount. Issue is, that now it is not working as I expected. It shows results as first column is sorted and in the end is second column sorted. Depends if I choose ASC or DESC.

I need to achieve   something like merge this two columns into one and than sort. Like this:

```
id | name | price | discount_price
3 | test 4 | 130  | 10*
4 | test 5 | 80* | 0
1 | Test 1 | 150  | 50*
2 | test 3 | 200*  | 0
4 | test 2 | 130  | 300*
```

Is it possible in mysql? Or should sort this afterwards in php ? Thank you for helping.

Comment: 10,80,50,200,300 doesn't make much sense (at least to me).

Comment: Same question i have how you can make unnecessary sorting. 10,80,50,200,300. This also to me not any sense.

if you want 10,50,80,200,300. Then  you can get from the below query:

`Select id,name,price,discount_price, if(discount_price=0,price,discount_price) as sort_order FROM table order by sort_order ASC`

Comment: Didn't you ask this yesterday, nobody undestood your requirements and the question got deleted

Comment: +1 for `if(discount_price=0,price,discount_price) as sort_order FROM table order by sort_order ASC`.  More elegant than my answer.

Comment: **If you make the data make sence, it helps us make sence of your question** You have one row with a larger discount_price that the actual price. **Help us to help you** Which just leads us to believe you have rushed the table showing your requirements as well

Comment: @user2703330  Did this solve the issue?

Comment: What's your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: Hi, I am very sorry but I was away so I cant reply. Looks like solution from @Manish is the exactly what I needed but I need to test it properly first.  In any case Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this (the field definitions in the table creation are pseudocode):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE sort (id INT, name VARCHAR, INT price, INT discount_price, INT actual_price) ;
INSERT INTO sort (id, name, price, discount_price)
    SELECT id, name, price, discount_price
    FROM original_table ;
UPDATE sort SET actual_price = price WHERE discount_price = 0 ;
UPDATE sort SET actual_price = discount_price WHERE discount_price != 0 ;
SELECT id, name, price, discount_price FROM sort ORDER BY actual_price ;
```